# System.Linq.Dynamic.Core GroupBy then Select

Tags: linq, dynamic, iqueryable

I have a service that return `IQueryable<T>`.
I want to make this call with dynamic linq;

```
masterService.Grid().GroupBy(x=>x.Operation).Select(x=>new{Operation=x.Key});
```

I try below code;

```
masterService.Grid().GroupBy("Operation").Select("new(Operation.Key as Operation)");
```

But it throw error with message below;

> No property or field 'Operation' exists in type 'IGrouping`2'

How can I do this?

Comment: `"new(Operation.Key as Operation)"` should be `"new(Key as Operation)"`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for quick response. it works. One more question, if Operation  is an enum may I use OperationEnum[Operation]. And I didn't find Mark As Answer :(

Comment: Sorry, I meant OperationEnum[Key]

Comment: If you can use it in the static LINQ, then you can use it in dynamic LINQ as well. And don't bother for answer mark, these are just comments, not answers :)

Comment: Hi,
Thanks, I am new at stackoverflow :)
I have one more question;
I have a grid interface and I am giving right to user create multiple group with data.
In returned data, I need each group key value,
I pass grouped parameter with string array like;
`["Brand","Model","FuelType"]`
Then I need json value like that;
`{
  Key:"Toyota",
    {
       Key:"Corolla",
        {
            Key:"Diesel"
        }
    }
}`
I can do that with dynamic linq?
I search on internet but i didn' t find any information.
Or do I give up?
Thanks.

Comment: Consider posting it as separate question. The general rule is single question per post. And you may get real answers, not just comments like here (because this was pretty basic).

Comment: Ok,Thank you very much.